# WEB API in asp.net web forms MapHttpRoute

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-web-api

I've been racking on my brain on this for a little bit now.  I have built a web api, and I am now moving it to a web forms application.  Every tutorial I have read says do it the way I am attempting to do.  I have also checked the web for an answer to this, but they all suggest things I have already tried.  The error I am getting is:

```
System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection does not contain a definition for MapHttpRoute
```

Here are my namespaces and my Application_Start method:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Http" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>

<script language="C#" runat="server">

void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) {


    RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "apiCall",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{key}/{args}",
           defaults: new { args = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
       );

}
```

Any help as to what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the correct using statement? I think this is the one you want:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh835153(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried this, and it is looks like is not available System.Web.Http.HttpRouteCollection. I have definitely made a reference to the System.Web.Http dll.

Comment: Why do you have the System.Web.Routing namespace? You should use one type or routes or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hepl, but I ended up adding my web api to my project through Visual Studio, and it fixed itself.  I had just been trying to add in windows explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and I fixed it by adding this assembly reference :
System.Web.Http.WebHost

[image: Assembly Reference]